# missing operator using database (unity3d)

Tags: database

i am using database in my game the query is giving an error of missing operator my code is

```
public void Execute(){

jsScript = Camera.main.GetComponent(); ReadStudent(Application.dataPath+"/dictionary.accdb","dict","word","word","=",jsScript.words);

}
internal void ReadStudent(string filetoread,string tableName, string itemToSelect, string wCol, string wPar, string wValue){

  string connection = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=" + filetoread;
  Debug.Log(connection);

    string sqlQuery ="SELECT word FROM"+ tableName +"WHERE" + wCol + wPar+"'"+wValue+"";

    OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(connection);
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sqlQuery,con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("dic");


    try{
        con.Open();
        OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(reader);
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception ex){
     //text = dt.Rows[3][1].ToString();
        Debug.Log(ex.ToString());
    }

    finally{
        if (con.State!=ConnectionState.Closed){
            con.Close();
        }
        con.Dispose();
    }

    if (dt.Rows.Count>0){
            text = dt.Rows[0]["word"].ToString();
    }
}
```

it is giving error : System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'word FROMdictWHEREword='MX'.

Answer (score 0):

As evident by the error, your `SELECT` statement is lacking spaces:

```
[SELECT] 'word FROMdictWHEREword='MX'.
```

This malformed SQL is created by the following line:

```
string sqlQuery ="SELECT word FROM"+ tableName +"WHERE" + wCol + wPar+"'"+wValue+"";
```

Just add the spaces to it, and you should be fine:

```
string sqlQuery = "SELECT word FROM "+ tableName + " WHERE " + wCol + " " + wPar + " '" + wValue + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're missing spaces from the command:

```
select word FROMdictWHEREword='MX'
```

should read something like

```
select word FROM dict WHERE word = 'MX'
```